# Reading data from an Ohaus Defender 3000 with a RS-232 shield

Tags: serial, arduino-mega, rs232

I have a project where we have to read the weight from an Ohaus Defender 3000 by using an Arudino Mega 2560 and a RS-232 shield. Right now we have the RX of the Arduino to the TX of the shield, and the TX of the Arduino to the RX of the shield. In our code, we get both the RX and the TX lights of the shield to light up but we can't receive data from the scale into the Arduino. Could someone help me understand what is going on or am I doing something wrong. This is the following code that I used for the Arduino. I found this code at: [Reading Arduino Serial Input](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/48969/reading-arduino-serial-input). Thank you for the help in advance.

```
#define HWSERIAL Serial1

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  HWSERIAL.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  int incomingByte;

  if (Serial.available() > 0) {
    incomingByte = Serial.read();
    Serial.print("USB received: ");
    Serial.println(incomingByte, DEC);
    //HWSERIAL.print("USB received:");
    //HWSERIAL.println(incomingByte, DEC);
  }
  if (HWSERIAL.available() > 0) {
    incomingByte = HWSERIAL.read();
    Serial.print("UART received: ");
    Serial.println(incomingByte);
    //HWSERIAL.print("UART received:");
    //HWSERIAL.println(incomingByte);
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't know the specific instrument you're trying to connect to, but have you configured it to send output to its serial port with the speed you expect in your sketch (9600 baud)? Also, for troubleshooting, have you tried to connect your instrument to a PC (via usb to serial) to see if it outputs any data on the serial port?

Answer (score 1):

Can you provide a photo of your hardware setup, and the full code for your project?  Please use the "code sample" formatting widget (the "{}" icon) to surround the code section, and look at the preview to make sure the code is formatted correctly.

Just a guess, but you may have the TX/RX lines to the scale connected to 'Serial' on the Mega instead of 'Serial1'. That would definitely cause problems